# React Native and Android Studio licenses issue

Tags: react-native, android-studio, build

I'm having a problem with React Native and Android licenses.

My Android knowledge is dated, I do write React but have no experience with React Native. Which is why I hired someone to turn a progressive web app I made into a native one. But due to circumstances I now have to finish the final thing myself.

The app was created on a mac, I'm trying to run it on pc.
The app *does* build for both IOS and Android from the Microsoft Appcenter. So I know it works, but I want it to run locally as well.

After doing all the installing and running `react-native run-android` the build starts but halts due to unaccepted licenses.

I already had Android Studio installed. I have checked the SDK Manager for the correct package versions (with 'show package details').
Updated everything I can think of including reinstalling Android Studio for the nth time. After the first uninstall/reinstall it would put it into a directory suffixed with '1' probably because the original directory couldn't be deleted. Yet the environment variables still pointed to the one without the suffix.

Accepting the licenses through cli with `sdkmanager --licenses` *did* opt me to accept a couple of times, but it didn't match the number of unaccepted packages I get from the `react-native run-android` error and the error remained the same afterwards (forgot to pay attention to which packages I was accepting though).

Two curious things:
- the error seems to be looking for licenses in a folder `licenses` yet my Android Studio folder only contains a folder `license`
- the error states `Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio` but during the install of Android Studio I put mine in `C:\AndroidSDK` because it was whining about spaces.

Here is the error I get after running `react-native run-android`

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 905 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform-Tools in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform-Tools not accepted.
Checking the license for package SDK Patch Applier v4 in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package SDK Patch Applier v4 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android Emulator in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package Android Emulator not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Tools not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     patcher;v4 SDK Patch Applier v4
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     emulator Android Emulator
     tools Android SDK Tools
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
     platform-tools Android SDK Platform-Tools
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

error Failed to install the app. Please accept all necessary SDK licenses using SDK Manager: "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses". Run CLI with --verbo
se flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     patcher;v4 SDK Patch Applier v4
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     emulator Android Emulator
     tools Android SDK Tools
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
     platform-tools Android SDK Platform-Tools
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:629:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\foo\bar\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAl
lDevices.js:74:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\foo\bar\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:15
8:41)
    at C:\Users\foo\bar\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\foo\bar\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: No, unfortunately I never solved this one :-/